# Remove padding for an empty element

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm generating a page for an upcoming portal site, and I've got an HTML element with some optional content. I'd like the element to not render if it is empty, but adding some padding to it causes it to render. How do I add padding to the content, but only if content is present?

```
.someElement{padding-top: 5px;}
```

HTML in question:

```
<div class="someElement">With padded content</div>
<div class="someElement"><!-- shouldn't render since it has no content --></div>
```

Basically, I'd like the second element, above, to not take up any space. I'm testing in all major browsers, using XHTML 1.1 doctype.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You can do the trick with the CSS3 pseudo-class :empty

```
.someElement
{
    // your standard style
}
.someElement:empty
{
    display:none;
}
```

Sadly Internet explorer doesn't support that feauture yet. For all the other browsers it shall do just fine...

Comment: This does not seem to work for visually empty elements. Elements containing a child, where the child has "display:none", count as non-empty.

Answer (score 7):

Give the element an `id` attribute. You can then use Javascript to check it's innerHTML property once the page has loaded. If innerHTML has a length of zero, then you can set it's display property to none. [This page](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) might help if you don't know your javascript.

This is still a mucky way to play. If you know the element shouldn't be rendered before you serve the page it would be better to omit it altogether. If you don't want to omit the element, just hide it, then force it into hiding; `style="display: none"`

Comment: You don't need to necessarily give it an `id` property. But +1 regardless, I think JavaScript is the way to go here. Have a look at jQuery to make this easy: http://jquery.com/

Comment: Pages that are rendered like this, look a bit silly - first it's loaded and the CSS is applied (rendering a 5px space, as in this example) and then the JS fixes are applied, the space disappears.

Comment: @naivists - agreed, but it's difficult to get around if you're serving static HTML.

Comment: @naivists To avoid that you could do the opposite: initially hide all of the elements, and then show non-empty elements using Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

```
<style>
.someElement{padding-top: 5px; display:table;}
</style>
<div class="someElement">With padded content</div>
<div class="someElement"><!-- shouldn't render since it has no content --></div>
```

Adding display:table; should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If it's *necessary* to have the `div.someElement` in the HTML, the best CSS/HTML way to do that would be to add an extra `div` around the added content that has the padding property

```
.someElement > div{padding-top:5px;}

<div class="someElement"><div>Content</div></div>
```

Otherwise, do as Pekka says, or take a look at having javascript do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Give the empty element a different class (say `someHiddenElement`) when you are generating the content. Then add `someHiddenElement { display: none }` to your style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a CSS only way to do that.

I would try to decide whether the element is rendered at the time I know whether there will be any content in it. That is probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use padding on container, use margin on content. Than when there is no content, container remains invisible.

Comment: It doesn't work, I have a background color that still shows.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you populate the optional `div`, if there is no text to put in it, try changing the CSS `display` property to `none.` According to [this source](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm) (and others), `display: none` removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code.