# How to not display css padding when span element is empty

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to solve the following problem.

If you run this code you will notice blue and red elements.
How can I hide  the 'red element' when there is no text to display (span is empty). And I would like to do the same thing with 'blue element' when there is no text inside it shouldn't be visible.
The reason why is displayed is padding, but I would like to have padding because it looks nice.
I am sure you guys are best of the best and find solution.
Regards!

```css
.myClassDer {
  font-size: 34px;
  color:white;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto; 
}

.myClassDie {
  font-size: 34px;
  color:black;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<span class="myClassDer">here</span>
<span class="myClassDie"></span>
```

Comment: You want an answer with html css only or is JS or Jquery fair game?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS style padding for an empty element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992822/css-style-padding-for-an-empty-element)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't require [support for IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), you can use pseudo-state `:empty` ([here for more examples](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/) ) to reset padding for all instances of `.myClassDie` without content, using the following code.

```
.myClassDie:empty
{
   padding:0;
}
```

Updating your working example, it becomes:

```
.myClassDer
{
  font-size: 34px;
  color:white;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto; 
}

.myClassDie
{
  font-size: 34px;
  color:black;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto; 
}

.myClassDie:empty
{
   padding:0;
}

<span class="myClassDer">here</span>
<span class="myClassDie"></span>
<span class="myClassDie">ClassDie but with content</span>
```

In which I inserted two `<span class="myClassDie">` to show you the behaviour with and without content.

Due to effective invisibility of "*empty*" case, if you want a more compact solution, you can collapse the two separate rules into only one, simply setting:

```
.myClassDie:not(:empty)
{
   font-size: 34px;
   color:black;
   background: red;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 25px;
   padding: 7px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto; 
}
```

In this case, *only if* `.myClassDie` *is not empty*, you'll apply all properties.

This is equivalent for this specific case, but if you want to see this DIV also if empty, limiting only to reset padding (for example because it has fixed size or borders), you must use first solution, not the more compact one.

---

**Little precisation about :empty pseudo-class**

Previous examples run correctly only if empty elements are effectively *empty*, this means that this code `<span class="myClassDie"></span>` is correctly targeted, but this one (that contains a whitespace) `<span class="myClassDie"> </span>` isn't.

In general, this could be an issue because often code is dynamically generated or otherwise contains white spaces due to code indentation.

In the past, [Mozilla introduced its proprietary pseudo-class `:-moz-only-whitespace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-only-whitespace), but no other browser currently supports this yet.

W3 also tried to solve this kind of problems, initially with analogue [`:blank`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/) pseudo-class (again with no browser support) in "Selectors Level 3", but this did not have expected success.

So, since [beginning of 2018](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#changes-2018-02), W3 modified its definition *to represent empty user input, rather than empty elements* and contemporarily [modified :empty definition](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo) to consider also white-spaces, but currently [this last feature is not implemented too in different browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Your example would be more useful if you demonstrated the class in question both containing text and empty.

Comment: @isherwood Edit my answer according to your suggestion

Comment: I did once. :-) Add it back in if you like.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, but you guys solved it in seconds, Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 3):

Empty pseudo class only checks for empty text

```
.myClassDie:empty{
   padding:0;
}
```

But for whitespaces use blank pseudo class

```
.myClassDie:blank{
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a css pseudoclass `empty` which you could use here:

```
.myClassDie:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

[Your updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ucx0usm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick with the CSS3 pesudo-class :empty

```
span:empty{
  padding:0;
}
```

> Note: using above selector you will not have to worry about which span
>   has value and which one has not. it will reset padding for those span
>   which are blank (empty).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use above piece of code to hide the empty span's padding.

```
span:empty {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you `:empty` also read the below like.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes

```
.myClassDie:empty {padding:0;}
```